# Change the color of an object after tkinter has been initiated

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, colors

I am trying to make a circle in tkinter change colors after the window has been initiated. I've looked [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991717/can-you-change-the-attributes-of-a-python-canvas-object-after-creation#) question, and I know how to change the colors after stating the variable. I'm trying to make a traffic light (much like the person in the question I looked at), but I can't update the color change after the screen comes up. This is what I have so far

```
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
light_1 = canvas.create_oval(*coordinates here*, fill='green')
root.mainloop()
```

and to change the color use `canvas.itemconfig(light_1, fill='blue')`

and I can't just do a `time.sleep(1)` because then the `root.mainloop()` is only reached *after* i change the color. There is no visual feedback of it changing

Comment: user the method `root.after(1000,foo)` instead of `time.sleep`? Or have a button execute that function..? (note that time is in milliseconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `time.sleep()` anywhere in tkinter code because it blocks the tkinter mainloop from running. The solution is to add your code to the tkinter mainloop using the `after` method:

```
def change_color():
    canvas.itemconfig(light_1, fill='blue')

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
light_1 = canvas.create_oval(*coordinates here*, fill='green')
root.after(1000, change_color) # 'after' uses milliseconds, so 1,000 = 1 second
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That seems like the exact thing I was looking for. I'm not able to test it out right now, but I'm sure it will work! Thanks!